# Java - Traversing nested JSON level by level

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json formatted string that would look like this:

```
{
   "rule":[
      {
         "name":"group_A",
         "percent":60,
         "group":[
            {
               "name":"group_A_1",
               "percent":30
            },
            {
               "name":"group_A_2",
               "percent":70
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"group_B",
         "percent":40,
         "group":[
            {
               "name":"group_B_1",
               "percent":40,
               "group":[
                  {
                     "name":"group_B_1_a",
                     "percent":55,
                     "group":[
                        {
                           "name":"group_B_1_a_1",
                           "percent":35
                        },
                        {
                           "name":"group_B_1_a_2",
                           "percent":65
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"group_B_1_b",
                     "percent":45
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"group_B_n",
               "percent":60,
               "group":[
                  {
                     "name":"group_B_n_a",
                     "percent":35
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"group_B_n_b",
                     "percent":65
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Based on these rules, I would like to generate for each user, in which group they would end up at. For example, for the first level, the user has 60% chance of being in `group_A`, and 40 % of being in `group_B`. I would use some random generator to generate a random number from 0 - 100 (I'm using Random java util class). If I get 0-40, I would place the user in group_B, and from 41 - 100, place it in `group_A`. If I get 50 for example, the user should fall into `group_A`. In here, I would start again, generate number from 0 - 100, and if I get 35, I would place user in `group_A_2`. In the end, the output would be something like `group_A/group_A_2`.

I would like to traverse level by level, and get the result, and based on the result, I would like to go into deeper into specific level. I'm currently not really sure how I would go about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about using JSONPath?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would like to do this using standard json library if possible.